# Multer is not able to recieve the file name in req.file

Tags: node.js, express, multer

I am using multer in node.js. But I am always getting req.files undefined. I am not able to rectify the error. Can anyone tell me about this error how to resolve it.

Comment: Please try to explain more or post some snippets to understand your problem.

Comment: @ narayansharma91 let me add some code.

Comment: Hi Karan, Welcome to SO!. Please go through => [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)